# Custom div draggable function - window boundaries?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function to drag a div by a handle:

```
function enableDragging(ele) {
    var dragging = dragging || false,
        x, y, Ox, Oy,
        current;
    enableDragging.z = enableDragging.z || 1;
    var grabber = document.getElementById("wrapId");
    grabber.onmousedown = function (ev) {
        ev = ev || window.event;
        var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        current = target.parentNode;
        dragging = true;
        x = ev.clientX;
        y = ev.clientY;
        Ox = current.offsetLeft;
        Oy = current.offsetTop;
        current.style.zIndex = ++enableDragging.z;

        document.onmousemove = function (ev) {
            ev = ev || window.event;
            pauseEvent(ev);
            if (dragging == true) {

                var Sx = ev.clientX - x + Ox,
                    Sy = ev.clientY - y + Oy;

                current.style.left = Math.max(Sx, Math.min(document.body.offsetWidth - Sx, 0)) + "px";
                current.style.top = Math.max(Sy, Math.min(document.body.offsetHeight - Sy, 0)) + "px";
                document.body.focus();
                document.onselectstart = function () {
                    return false;
                };
                ev.ondragstart = function () {
                    return false;
                };
                document.body.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
                document.body.style.cursor = "default";
                return false;
            }
        }
        document.ondragstart = function () {
            return false;
        }
        document.onmouseup = function (ev) {
            ev = ev || window.event;
            dragging && (dragging = false);
            if (ev.preventDefault) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            } else {
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                e.returnValue = false;
            }

            document.body.style.MozUserSelect = "text";
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
            //toggleEnableSelectStart(true);
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

I am trying to set boundaries to that the div cannot be dragged outside of the bounds of the actual browser window.

The above function accomplished 50% of this, it wont let the user drag the div outside of the top left and left bounds. However it left the user drag it outside bottom and right..

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the minimum between the value you had calculated with the width/ height boundaries of the window minus the width of/height of the div:

```
current.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(Sx, Math.min(document.body.offsetWidth - Sx, 0)), document.body.offsetWidth - current.offsetWidth) + "px";
current.style.top = Math.min(Math.max(Sy, Math.min(document.body.offsetHeight - Sy, 0)), document.body.offsetHeight - current.offsetHeight) + "px";
```

**edit:**

Something along these lines (mind, this is quickly written, not in the same format as yours!)

http://jsfiddle.net/WKLa7/1/

Comment: sorry, got to consider the width of the div as well

Comment: Still i can drag the div outside on the right and bottom, only top and left boundaries work :/

Comment: @Alosyius, sorry for not being clear, hopefully the fiddle will elaborate